# how to add interstitial ads on cardView?

Tags: java, android, admob

How to show interstitial ads?
I have a custom cardView with many Intent that go to new Activity. The concept is like this, when user clicks the item on cardView, I want to display Interstitial ads before the new activity is appear.
I want to know

2/How to show interstitial ads?
I have a custom cardView with many Intent that go to new Activity. The concept is like this, when user clicks the item on cardView, I want to display Interstitial ads before the new activity is appear.
I want to know

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Recipes> mData;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialdAd;
    RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Recipes> mData){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view ;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_recipe,viewGroup,false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder myHolder, final int i) {



        myHolder.recipeTitle.setText(mData.get(i).getRecipeName());
        myHolder.img_recipe_thumbnail.setImageResource(mData.get(i).getThumbnail());
        myHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {





                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,RecipeActivity.class);




                intent.putExtra("RecipeName",mData.get(i).getRecipeName());
                intent.putExtra("RecipeIngredients",mData.get(i).getRecipeIngredients());
                intent.putExtra("RecipeMethodTitle",mData.get(i).getRecipeMethodTitle());
                intent.putExtra("Recipe",mData.get(i).getRecipe());
                intent.putExtra("Thumbnail",mData.get(i).getThumbnail());

                    mContext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView recipeTitle;
        CardView cardView;
        ImageView img_recipe_thumbnail;

        MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);



            recipeTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_text);
            img_recipe_thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_img_id);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_id);


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use adListner for open activity after ads closed. ad your code into `onAdClosed()`

```
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked() {
        // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // start your next activity Intent here..
    }
});
```